# Tensorboard scalar look like a mess

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

I have built a deep constitutional network for MNIST dataset with `TensorLayer`. I used `RMS` optimizer and have a decay learning rate. But when using the `tensorboard` to fine-tune the model, I saw this in the loss curve, which I think is not normal. Can any body help?

[image: Horizontal Axis: STEP]
[image: Horizontal Axis: RELATIVE]

Have a deep convolutional network named `network` which is trained using the following code

```
data = pd.read_csv('data/train.csv')
data_x = data.drop('label',1).values
data_y = data['label'].values

num = len(data.index)
trainset = np.random.choice(num, int(num * 0.9), replace=False)

train_X = data_x[trainset,:].astype(np.float32)
valid_X = np.delete(data_x, trainset, axis=0).astype(np.float32)
train_y = data_y[trainset]
valid_y = np.delete(data_y, trainset, axis=0)
test_X = pd.read_csv('data/test.csv').values

network = ...

y = network.outputs
y_op = tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(y), 1, name='y_op')
cost = tl.cost.cross_entropy(y, y_, name='conv_cost')
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), y_)
acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
lr = tf.train.exponential_decay(0.001, global_step, 2560, 0.16, staircase=True)
train_op = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(lr, 0.9, momentum=0.3, epsilon=1e-4).minimize(cost, var_list=network.all_params)
tl.layers.initialize_global_variables(sess)
tl.utils.fit(sess, network, train_op, cost, X_train=train_X, y_train=train_y, x=X, y_=y_, X_val=valid_X, y_val=valid_y,
             acc=acc, batch_size=256, n_epoch=80, print_freq=1, eval_train=False, tensorboard=True, tensorboard_epoch_freq=1)
```

Comment: You'll need to also post the core components of your model for anyone to have any chance at providing a useful answer. There are a lot of things that can go wrong.

Comment: For me it looks like you're using the same folder and re-run the model a few times. Try to use a different folder for every single model/run (e.g. a timestamp or a distinct run_id)

Comment: ^ Try @sladomic's suggestion or try stopping and restarting tensorboard.

Comment: @sladomic I added my code in the question. Actually, the data is from two files `train.csv` and `test.csvt`. I just load and train the network once. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

OK. it turns that it the problem of the event files, all of which are put in one folder. It can be solved by removing all the other event files and restart tensorboard.